# Call ASP.NET pagemethod from external script

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, httpwebrequest, webmethod

#### Background

I have an ASP.NET site, hosted internally on our company's intranet server.  The site uses the client's default network credentials for authentication.  The main page for the site, `Default.aspx` contains the following web method that syncs some data from an Oracle server to an MS SQL server:

```
<WebMethod()> _
Public Shared Sub syncOracle()        
    OracleSync.MainSync()
End Sub
```

When I access that webmethod from site itself (say from a button on the page or something) it works fine and performs as expected.

#### Problem

I would like to setup a scheduled task on the server that calls this method on a period basis.  My approach so far has been to write a simple console script in VB that would access the web method via an `HTTPWebRequest`:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim myReq As HttpWebRequest = _
       WebRequest.Create("http://vm-prod1/dev/default.aspx/syncOracle")
    myReq.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials
    myReq.Method = "POST"
    myReq.ContentLength = 0

    Dim response As HttpWebResponse = CType(myReq.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)

    Console.WriteLine(response.StatusCode)

    Console.ReadKey()
End Sub
```

This returns an "OK" status of 200, but when I parse the actual response, I'm not getting the response that I get when I access the method from the page (instead, I get the code for the entire aspx page).  And the sync is not firing.

#### Question

Does anyone have any insight into either a better / different approach (maybe not using HttpWebRequests) or modification to my current approach that may work better?  Thank you in advance!

Comment: This has been discussed at work recently, one of our developers  suggested a clever way with capturing the event that is raised when a cookie is expiring and attaching anything he wants to do there. Then it sorts of work like a scheduler, based on what expiration time is given. He had a script written for it. The other implementation was using the scheduler with a VB Script, but I don't know the details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By far the easiest thing you could do is drop page methods and switch to using a simple Generic Handler.

With a generic handler you don't have all of the standard web forms page lifecycle and instead it gives you an extremely flexible and easy way to run processing like you've described.

So, I'd add a generic handler (.ashx) file to the project.  Put the code in you need to run.  Then simply execute the page from console script.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Don't know why I didn't think of that!